# Trouble installing NVIDIA drivers

Tags: release-loki, display, nvidia

This is my first time using any other OS than Windows/Mac. I am astounded by the amount of trouble I'm having trying to get my NVIDIA drivers to work.

Every time, after installing I get a black screen even after disabling nouveau drivers by typing

> nouveau.modeset=0

in the GRUB. I've also tried [this method](https://youtu.be/8qd7MFeIwXo) but it didn't work. I've manually enabled 'Software & Updates' and tried installing it that way, but it gets stuck at about 80% and gives me a black screen after rebooting. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using a Windows 10/Elementary OS dualboot setup. I'm happy to provide additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by turning off secure boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

First, delete every nvidia driver related package you have tried to install. Then do the following:

Check what drivers are avaliable for your system:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices | grep -o nvidia-[[:digit:]]*
```

Then install the one you want (replace XXX with the correct number):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-XXX
```

In case you have Optimus Technology you would also want to install this:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime
```

In case you want to fine tune your settings, is recommended to install nvidia-settings as well:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
```

Comment: Just open up terminal and type all this in?

Comment: Yes. But one at a time! Also, if you DON'T have a laptop you don't need to install `nvidia-prime`.